# Get from user string and switch all the following alpha

Tags: c

I've got this work towards my degree,

I need to get from the standard input a string, and replace all the followings letters with this pattern:

For every following letter, take the `first` letter and the `end` letter and replace them with `first-end`,

For example, for the input of `"abcd"`, change the string to `"a-d"`,
or for the input `"abcdABCD1234fabc"` replace with `"a-dA-D1234fa-c"`.

**Note** that Uppercase letter and lowercase letter are diffrents and not following, 
and replace only letters and not following numbers..

I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void replace(char str[], int start, int end) {
    str[start + 1] = 45;
    str[start + 2] = str[end];
    strcpy(str + (start + 3), str + (end + 1));
}

void search(char str[]) {
    int start, end, pointer, counter;
    start = end = pointer = counter = 0;
    for (; str[pointer] != 0; pointer++) {
        if (str[pointer] + 1 != str[pointer + 1]) {
            if (counter >= 2 && isalpha(str[pointer])) {
                replace(str, start, end);
                pointer -= counter - 2;
            }
            counter = end = 0;
            start = pointer + 1;
        } 
        else {
            counter++;
            end = pointer + 1;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char str[80];
    while (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) != NULL) {
        search(str);
        printf("%s", str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For the start the code all looks fine and all works, but when I start playing with different inputs things got little bit complicated..

When I input the array :

```
abcdef12345ABCDxyz abc abc abc
```

my output is:

```
a-f12345A-Dx-z a-c bc a-c
```

but the requested output is:

```
a-f12345A-Dx-z a-c a-c a-c
```

and when I try to be little bit more complicated and input:

```
abcdef12345ABCDxyz abc abc abc abc abc
```

he also short my numbers and give me this output:

```
a-f15A-Dx-z a-ca-c ac aa-c a-c a-c
```

the requested output is:

```
a-f12345A-Dx-z a-c a-c a-c a-c a-c
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: If "ab" is to be replaced by "a-b" then this means your string can actually grow longer. So I don't believe doing the replacement "in-place" is going to work, even if you fix your other problems.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/I6vS1zwe3) shows exactly what you desired. Not only that, the desired output is given in my machine, too.

Comment: If you have a _lot_ of `ab`, it _will_ overflow the buffer. But, note that `ab` --> `ab` and _not_ `a-b` as you desire. Otherwise, it seems to work for all other inputs.

Comment: `strcpy(str+(start+3), str+(end+1));` is not valid. From the man page: *"The source and destination strings should not overlap, as the behavior is undefined."* You'll need to use `memmove` instead.

Comment: thx user3386109 thats fix my prog, insted of srycpy i use memmove,
and thx for everyone else who try to help,
using ubunto 16.4 rohan bari :)